# Accord du participe passé en présence d'unités de mesure

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé, compléments

Ce qui suit est extrait de la page 155 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> The past participle of certain intransitively used verbs accompanied by a unit of price, weight, distance, length, time, etc., is invariable.
>
> 1. les **deux heures** que j’ai **couru** (intransitive)
>      *But*: les **dangers** que j’ai **courus** (transitive)
> 2. les cent kilos que j’ai **pesé**
>      *But*: les paquets que j’ai **pesés**

En tant que néophyte, je suis perplexe. Puisque tous les noms (voire, les antécédents du pronom relatif « que ») sont pluriels, pourquoi est-ce que le participe passe ne s'accorde pas toujours avec eux ?
Par exemple, dans 1, comment est-ce que « couru » peut être à la fois transitif et intransitif ?

Compte tenu du fait que ce livre pourrait se fourvoyer, voici un extrait de [la page 72](http://books.google.com/books?id=Pd4yTKdJrnwC&pg=PA72&dq=%22millions+francs+que%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=DZwBU7OPOYaiiAf184CABw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22millions%20francs%20que%22&f=false%3a) de *Les Césars* par le comte Franz de Champagny. Pourquoi est-ce que **prétendu** n'y est pas au pluriel masculin ?

> Le dernier équivaut à 4 sesterces. Le revenu public aurait donc été depuis la victoire de Pompée (692) de 540 millions sesterces (104,700,000 francs). - C'est environ 330 millions francs que Cicéron aurait **prétendu** employer en achat des terres.
>
> Cicéron en 698 (pro Sextio '25) semble fixer à 40 millions francs seulement le
>   revenu de l'état; il est clair qu'il ne parle que des revenus anciens.

Les « 330 millions francs » ne sont-ils pas objet direct dans cette phrase ?

Answer (score 8):

Les exemples que tu cites répondent à la règle générale  de l'accord du participe passé avec avoir, à savoir que :

**Le participe passé employé avec *avoir* s’accorde avec son complément d'objet direct (c.o.d.) placé avant et reste invariable s’il n’y a pas de c.o.d. ou si ce c.o.d. est placé après.**

> Les dangers que j’ai courus.

→ Ici le verbe courir est transitif, il a un **c.o.d.** : « dangers ».

> Les deux heures que j’ai couru.

→ Ici le verbe courir est intransitif, « deux heures » n'est pas c.o.d. mais il est considéré comme un ensemble continu indivisible, complément circonstanciel (de temps).

Il en irait de même avec :

> Les dix kilomètres que j’ai couru.

→ « dix kilomètres » n'est pas c.o.d. mais un tout indivisible complément circonstanciel (de distance).

L'analyse est la même avec :

> Les paquets que j’ai pesés.

→ Accord du participe passé avec le c.o.d. « paquets ».

> Les cent kilos que j’ai pesé.

→ Pas d'accord, puisque pas de  c.o.d. avant le verbe.

D'autres exemples où la même règle s'applique :

> Les efforts que ce travail m’a coûtés.

→ « Efforts » est c.o.d. placé avant le verbe.

> Les dix mille euros que cette voiture m’a coûté.

→ Pas de c.o.d. avant le verbe mais un complément circonstanciel, somme considérée comme un ensemble continu.

Je cite Grevisse (édition 1975) :

> **Participe passé de certains verbes intransitifs :**
>   Certains verbes intransitifs : *coûter, valoir, peser, mesurer, marcher, courir, vivre, dormir, régner, durer, reposer*, peuvent être accompagnés d'un complément circonstanciel de prix, de valeur, de poids, de durée, de distance, et., qu'il faut se garder de prendre pour un objet direct : le participe passé de ces verbes est invariable.

Par ailleurs je voudrais redire quelque chose que j'ai déjà dit sur ce forum.
Les règles d'accord du participe passé en français, et surtout du participe passé avec avoir, sont tout à fait artificielles et ne répondent à aucune logique grammaticale. Ces règles qui n'existaient pas en ancien français ont été introduites entre les XV<sup>è</sup> et le XIX<sup>è</sup> siècles. (Pour moi citer un exemple du XIX<sup>è</sup> siècle (Champagny) n'a pas vraiment de valeur de témoignage).
Et voir ce que je te disais déjà [ici](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/la-reflexion-envers-la-question-la-concordance-dans-une-relative-clause-avec) à propos de l'accord du participe passé.

Comment: De toute façon, dans l'exemple de Champagny, les millions de francs en questions **sont le C.O.D. de *employer*, pas celui de *aurait prétendu*** (le C.O.D. de ce verbe est l'infinitif *employer*). Rien à signaler. Circulez.

Answer (score 3):

Dans aucun des exemples, je ne vois de COD placé avant le participe passé, donc je ne vois aucun exception à la règle à expliquer.  Ça ne fait que confirmer les doutes déjà exprimés sur la qualité de la grammaire que tu cites.

> Les deux heures que j’ai couru.

Il s'agit de complément de durée, pas d'objet direct.

> C'est environ 330 millions francs que Cicéron aurait prétendu employer en achat des terres.

Le COD est "employer 330 millions [*de* manquant à la copie ou tour tombé en désuétude?] francs en achat de terres".

> les cent kilos que j’ai pesé

Le cas le plus difficile.  S'il s'agit de mon poids, je ne vois pas de COD mais un type grammatical que j'ai du mal à identifier (j'aurais dit que c'est un attribut mais le [TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/peser) parle de *complément d'objet interne* qui est une terminologie qui ne m'est pas familière).  S'il s'agit d'autre chose, j'aurais accordé (*Je croyais avoir déjà vu de l'or dans ma vie, mais les cents kilos que j'ai pesés hier dépassent en une fois tout ce que j'avais vu combiné.*

Comment: Je suis d'accord sur le peu de crédit à accorder en général à cette grammaire mais il se trouve ici que la règle est correcte (accord avec le c.o.d. quand il est placé avant le verbe). [Complément d'objet interne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_interne), mais je ne pense pas que ce soit applicable au cas cités par le P.O.

Comment: @Laure, la règle est bien appliquée, mais la citation présente ce cas d'application comme une exception à la règle plutôt que d'expliquer en quoi il ne s'agit simplement pas de COD.