# Ces locutions nominales ne sont pas les objets directs ?

Tags: grammaire

Je ne comprends pas la raison pour laquelle [ces syntagmes nominaux](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8815) ne sont pas des objets directs ?

> > Les deux heures que j’ai couru.
>
> → Ici le verbe courir est intransitif, « deux heures » n'est pas c.o.d. mais il est considéré comme un ensemble continu indivisible, complément circonstanciel (de temps).
>
> Il en irait de même avec :
>
> > Les dix kilomètres que j’ai couru.
>
> → « dix kilomètres » n'est pas c.o.d. mais un tout indivisible complément circonstanciel (de distance).
>
> L'analyse est la même avec : ..
>
> Les cent kilos que j’ai pesé.
>
> → Pas d'accord, puisque pas de  c.o.d. avant le verbe.
>
> D'autres exemples où la même règle s'applique :
>   ...
>
> > Les dix mille euros que cette voiture m’a coûté.
>
> → Pas de c.o.d. avant le verbe mais un complément circonstanciel, somme considérée comme un ensemble continu.

Comment: *On n'embrasse pas pourquoi*, cause d'une interrogation, c'est déconseillé, voire prohibé dans certains cercles littéraires; parfois *on ne perçois pas pourquoi* si l'on veut rester dans le domaine sensoriel, ou tout simplement *on ne comprends pas pourquoi*.

Comment: Cette question supplémentaire n'a aucune justification. À la limite pourrais-tu mettre un commentaire à la réponse en question, à la limite ...

Comment: @Laure: Au vu de votre commentaire, je me renseigner sur ceci sur http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/524/les-questions-supplementaires-dans-laffiche-original

Comment: @LePressentiment: Tu ne poses aucune nouvelle question. Demander pourquoi un complément circonstanciel n'est pas un COD n'est pas plus une question que demander pourquoi une voiture n'est pas un avion... Si la voiture avait des ailes on l'appellerait un avion. Si un complément est un COD on l’appelle COD...

Comment: @LePressentiment: Si tu avais demandé en commentaire ce qu'était un complément circonstanciel je t'aurais renvoyé sur une page l'expliquant. [Ici](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/compl%C3%A9ment_circonstanciel) ou [ici](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-15198.php) mais tu aurais pu le trouver tout seul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Les compléments qui représentent **une mesure** sont considérés comme des **compléments adverbiaux** ("circonstanciels"), au même titre que, par exemple, le nom propre dans *J'habite Montréal*. On ne peut pas vraiment creuser à un niveau beaucoup plus profond, et je ne suis pas sûr en quoi la question est différente de l'original!

En grammaire (je dirais même *surtout* en grammaire!) comme en puériculture il y quand même a une limite aux nombres de "pourquoi" qu'on peut enchaîner!

Comment: La grammaire est ennuyeuse, la conclusion est savoureuse !