# Comment analyser "Il pèse cinquante kilos." ?

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe, compléments

Comment analyser cette phrase :

> Il pèse cinquante kilos.

Il = sujet

pèse = verbe

cinquante kilos = complément circonstanciel de quantité

Est-ce que c'est correct ?

Comment: [*Le complément circonstanciel est un mot ou un groupe de mots qui apporte des précisions sur les circonstances de l'action exprimée par la phrase.*](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/le-complement-circonstanciel-80.php). J'imagine donc que oui !

Comment: Voir aussi: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8812/accord-du-participe-pass%c3%a9-en-pr%c3%a9sence-dunit%c3%a9s-de-mesure

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Well now I'm even more confused than I was before. Here I got the answer that cinquante kilos is a COD, and on that site you linked it says cent kilos isn't a COD.... (Sorry for using English, it would take me two hours to write this in French.)

Comment: @lmc, it's just that the answers here are wrong, except one, so far.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est possible d'imaginer un scénario alambiqué où la personne pèse un poids (un morceau de métal) de 50 kg et qu'on omette le déterminant et tout autre complément parce que ce serait évident en voyant la personne le faire. Un cas limite.

Comment: @Survenant: Oui, je sais, mais sans plus de contexte, l'autre possibilité est la plus probable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La fonction grammaticale que vous cherchez est [**complément essentiel de mesure**](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-42633.php).

> On dit qu'un complément est essentiel :
>
> a) quand sa construction, avec ou sans préposition, dépend du verbe lui-même;
>
> b) quand le verbe ne peut, sans sa présence, avoir un sens.

Ce n'est pas **complément d'objet** du verbe parce que `cinquante kilos` n'est pas objet de l'action `peser`. Ce n'est pas facile à expliquer mais je vais essayer : en grammaire, l'objet désigne une réalité *externe* à l'action décrite par le verbe (sauf cas particulier comme l'objet interne 'vivre sa vie'). Or ici, non seulement `cinquante kilos` n'est pas une entité en tant que telle (comme dans 'il pèse son fils'), mais ce n'est pas externe au verbe.

On ne peut pas dire non plus que ce soit un **complément circonstanciel** parce qu'on ne peut l'ôter sans compromettre l'intégrité de la proposition. Autrement dit, c'est plus qu'une circonstance de l'action `peser`, c'est un élément **essentiel** de ce verbe.

Quelques autres exemples de compléments essentiels (tirés de la même source) :

> Il ira **voir sa mère**. (*lieu*)
>
> La séance de cinéma dure **deux heures**. (*temps*)
>
> L'enfant se conduit **correctement**. (*manière*)
>
> Il mesure **un mètre quatre-vingts**. (mesure)

Comment: Bien expliqué !

Comment: Comment COD, COI, Complément circonstanciel et complément essentiel se combinent-ils ensemble ? Ou parle-t-on de concepts différents ? Il pèse 50kg le matin au réveil => Quid de l'analyse pour cette phrase-ci ?

Answer (score 2):

Le complément circonstanciel ajoute une précision. Si tu l'enlève de la phrase elle na va pas changer de sens.

Dans ton cas tu ne peux pas enlever "cinquante kilos".
"Cinquante kilos" est un complément d'objet direct. Il ajoute une précision tout en étant indispensable.

[Le complément circonstanciel](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/le-complement-circonstanciel-80.php)

[Le complément d'objet direct (COD)](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/le-complement-d-objet-direct-cod-84.php)

Answer (score 2):

Voici une explication en décomposant la phrase suivante:

> Il pèse cinquante kilos.
>
> ```
> Il      |       pèse      |        cinquante kilos.
>
>
>
> Sujet   |       Verbe     |    Complément d'Objet Direct (COD)
> ```

cinquante kilos. Est bien ici un COD car rattaché au verbe directement, sans préposition, il désigne l'être ou l'objet sur lequel porte l'action et répond aux questions qui ? ou quoi ? posées après le verbe.

---

Autres exemples:

> Je mange une pomme. (Je mange quoi ? Une pomme.)

En l'appliquant donc à notre phrase initiale:

> Il pèse cinquante kilos. (Il pèse combien ? Cinquante kilos.)

Answer (score 1):

Il  -- sujet
pèse -- verbe
cinquante kilos -- complément circonstanciel de mesure de poids ([ref1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_circonstanciel)) ([ref2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_d%27objet_direct))

Answer (score 1):

Attention :
« cinquante kilo » est un complément essentiel dit *de mesure*, et pas un complément d'objet.

Ici le verbe *peser* n'est pas prédicatif, comme dans « il pèse la valise », c'est quasiment un verbe d'état. Ce n'est pas non plus un complément circonstanciel (il n'est pas déplaçable et le sens de la proposition est très affecté par sa disparition : « cinquante kilo il pèse », « il pèse »).

Il y a une catégorie spéciale pour ce genre de compléments :

> j'ai couru 100 mètres.

> Il est huit heures.

C'est un complément de mesure. Un complément essentiel.